# How to use infinite scrolling in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, infinite-scroll

I am working on meteor. I need to implement infinite scrolling on my data inside data list. I don't know how to implement it. I have seen some infinite scrolling packages at atmosphere but i didn't get. As I am new to this technology I didn't understand how to use it.

```
Template.medicine.events({
  'change #Search_Criteria':function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
     myvalue=$(e.target).val();
    console.log(myvalue);
     Meteor.call('searched_medicines',myvalue,function(err,res)
   {
     if(res)
     {
       console.log(res);
       SessionStore.set("Medicinevalue",res);
     }
     else {
       console.log(err);
     }
   });
 },

 'input #search':function (event, template) {
         d = $(event.currentTarget).val();
        console.log(d);
        Meteor.call('fetchValues',myvalue,d,function(error,response)
      {
        if(response)
        {

          SessionStore.set("Medi_values",response);
        }
        else {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    }
});


Template.medicine.helpers({
  // Here will be helper for displaying data in client side//
  searched_val:function(){
    var a= SessionStore.get("Medicinevalue");
    // console.log(a);
    return a;
  },

  myfunction:function(){
    var mydata=SessionStore.get("Medi_values");
    return mydata;
  }

});
```

Thanks in Advance!!!!!

Comment: Since you are asking a very broad question you need to at lest provide all the necessary code to see what you are currently doing.  Can you provide your full Template code (JS + HTML).  You only provided your event handlers and helpers.  Based on that alone, I have no idea what your templates are actually doing.

Comment: [This meteor package](https://github.com/abecks/meteor-infinite-scroll) provides a step by step example in their [README.md](https://github.com/abecks/meteor-infinite-scroll/blob/master/README.md).  I would advise you first try using this package and follow the example to understand the main concept of how it could be done.  Then decide if you want to continue with this package, use a different one, or roll your own.

Comment: ok , let me see this package ... Thanks :)